# WCSession sendmessage is twice as slow after updating from 2.1 to 2.2

Tags: ios, watchos-2

The iOS application that I work on has an apple watch app that goes along with it. We recently started getting complaints that the GPS distance updates have slowed down and the watch is a few seconds behind the phone. I have been looking into this and wrote some test code, the reply block from `[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:message
                                       replyHandler:replyHandler
                                       errorHandler:errorHandler`

is definitely twice as slow in watchOS 2.2 vs 2.1. I have attached the test code below.

```
#pragma mark - Location Update.
/**
 * @description Provides an NSBlockOperation to be executed in an operation queue. This is an attempt to force serial
 * processing
 */
- (NSBlockOperation*)distanceUpdateBlock {
    NSBlockOperation *blockOp = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    __weak NSBlockOperation * weakOp = blockOp;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [blockOp addExecutionBlock:^{
        typeof(weakSelf) blockSafeSelf = weakSelf;
        typeof(weakOp) blockSafeOp = weakOp;

        if (!blockSafeOp.isCancelled) { // Make sure we haven't already been cancelled.
            __block NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
            __block BOOL completed = NO;
            void (^replyBlock)(NSDictionary*) =  ^(NSDictionary *message){
                if (!blockSafeOp.isCancelled) {
                    [blockSafeSelf processUserLocationOnWatch:message];

                    double replyTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
                    NSLog(@"Reply Time: %.03f", replyTime);
                    completed = YES;
                }

            };
            void (^failBlock)(NSError*) =  ^(NSError *error) {
                if (!blockSafeOp.isCancelled) {
                    double replyTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
                    NSLog(@"Reply Time Fail: %.03f", replyTime);
                    completed = YES;
                }
            };

            [self fetchUserLocationFromIphoneWithReplyHandler:replyBlock errorHandler:failBlock];
            do {
                usleep(10000); // 1/100th second wait to throttle evaluations (Don't worry - in final code I will subclass NSOperation and control when it actually finishes - this is for easy testing.)
            } while (!completed && !blockSafeOp.isCancelled && [blockSafeSelf isWatchReachable]); //(isWatchReachable just makes sure we have a session with the phone and it is reachable).
        }
    }];

    blockOp.completionBlock = ^{
        typeof(weakSelf) blockSafeSelf = weakSelf;
        typeof(weakOp) blockSafeOp = weakOp;
        if (!blockSafeOp.isCancelled) {
            [blockSafeSelf addOperationForLocationUpdate]; // since we are finished - add another operation.
        }
    };

    return blockOp;
}

- (void)addOperationForLocationUpdate {

    [distanceUpdateOperationQueue addOperation:[self distanceUpdateBlock]];
}

- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    [self addOperationForLocationUpdate];
}

- (void)stopUpdatingLocation {
    [distanceUpdateOperationQueue cancelAllOperations];
}

- (void)fetchUserLocationFromIphoneWithReplyHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *replyMessage))replyHandler errorHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError *error))errorHandler {
    if (self.isSessionActive) {
        NSDictionary *message = @{kWatchSessionMessageTag:kWatchSessionMessageUserLocation};

        if (self.isWatchReachable) {
            [[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:message
                                       replyHandler:replyHandler
                                       errorHandler:errorHandler
             ];
        } else {
            errorHandler(nil);
        }

    } else {
        [self activateSession];
        errorHandler(nil);
    }
}
```

The handler on the iPhone side simply get's the User location and calls the replyHandler with the encoded information.

The logs for time on 2.2 look like (consistently about a second)

Reply Time: 0.919

Reply Time: 0.952

Reply Time: 0.991

Reply Time: 0.981

Reply Time: 0.963

Same code on 2.1 looks like

Reply Time: 0.424

Reply Time: 0.421

Reply Time: 0.433

Reply Time: 0.419

Also, I've noticed that after 5 mins (300 seconds) the error handlers start getting called on the messages that have already had the reply handler called. I saw another thread where someone mentioned this as well, is anyone else having this happen and know why?

So, Q1 - has anyone run into this performance slow down and figured out how to keep the replyHandler running faster, or found a faster way to get updates?

Q2 - Solution for the errorHandler getting called after 5 mins.

Just a few things to eliminate - I have done my due diligence on testing the iOS code between receiving the message and calling the replyHandler. There is no change in the time to process between iOS 9.2/9.3. I have narrowed it down to this call. In fact, the way we did this in previous versions is now backing up the sendMessage's operationQueue. So now I am forcing a one at a time call with this test code. We don't get backed up anymore, but the individual calls are slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was running tests today on the same piece of code, using the same devices, and although the code has not changed, it is now running twice as fast as it initially did (in 2.1). Logs are coming in the range of .12 - .2 seconds. Only thing that has happened since then is software updates. Also, the fail block is no longer called after 5 mins. So both parts of this question are magically working. I am currently using iOS 9.3.4(13G35) and watch is at 2.2.2. Seems to have been an OS issue somewhere in the chain of processing the queue between the watch and the phone. All is good now.